# The implement of mutex in SICP Section 3.4

Tags: lisp, scheme, mutex, sicp

When the authors implement the mutex part of serializers, they use a list called `cell`. But the list only contains one element, so why not just use a variable?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Because a variable isn't a first-class value that you can pass to another function. In 3.4, the authors implement a `make-mutex` function that uses `clear!` as a helper function, which takes a cell. If the cell were represented by a mutable variable, then `clear!` would have to be defined inside `make-mutex!` to close over that variable. The same goes for the `test-and-set!` helper function.

They also could have used, say, a box instead of a cons cell.

Answer (score 5):

If a variable is used there instead of a list, the procedures `clear!` and `test-and-set!` won't work since Scheme is pass-by-value.